# Create a Custom Class to Parse a String

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, class-design

I've created a method that returns a string based on values looked up from NSUserDefaults.

```
- (NSString *) getString:(NSInteger *)intID {

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *strMyString;

    if ((int)intID == 1) {
        strMyString = [userDefaults stringForKey:kSomeStuff];
    } else {
        strMyString = [userDefaults stringForKey:kSomeOtherStuff];
    }

    // ... do a bunch of string parsing
    return strMyString; 
}
```

Works great. Except I have this method duplicated in a half dozen different view controllers classes. It seems like the perfect case for a custom class that can be shared by all the various view controllers. But I have no idea how to do that.
Any help is appreciated!
lq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to add a class that inherits from `NSObject` (named "StringMangler" or whatever), and put your (hopefully) stateless convenience method there as a static method:

```
+ (NSString *) getString:(NSInteger *)intID {
```

In your view controllers, `#import "StringMangler.h"` and then call

```
[StringMangler getString:myID];
```

Comment: Sorry for the rookie question, but this would all go in StringMangler.h and no accompanying StringMangler.m ?

Comment: Yes Lauren Quantrell. `StringMangler.h` is enough plus you have to create an object of `StringMangler` Class through which you can access the method `getString:`

Comment: @PARTH: your edit is absolutely NOT what I intended. The whole point of the static method is to avoid the hassle of creating and releasing an object just to make a one-line stateless method call.

Comment: @Lauren: your getString method would go in StringMangler.m, with a prototype of the method signature in StringMangler.h. In any class that needs to call getString, then, you only need to `#import` the .h file.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I am Sorry I misunderstood your answer and made the edit. But creating a static method is not a good idea. It is better to create and release objects when you want to use it. That enables you to get an extended use over the method. Afterall whats wrong with creating and releasing the object if you know the concept of memory management?

Comment: Musi, thanks for the clarification. All done and working sweetly!

Answer (score 2):

This would be a perfect use of a [category on `NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1). Then you could have methods like this:

```
- (NSString *)someStuff {
    return [self stringForKey:kSomeStuff];
}

- (NSString *)someOtherStuff {
    return [self stringForKey:kSomeOtherStuff];    
}
```

Then, when you need these values, you just write:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] someStuff];
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. But in this case the [//... do a bunch of string parsing] is a lot of string manipulating. But I'll keep that in mind for future uses.

Comment: So put that in a class method in a category on `NSString`. Point is, I don't recommend a subclass here because it doesn't seem like you'd ever need to create an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class and name it UserDefaultsHelper for example.  Put all the code you wrote you to handle read and writing to NSUserDefaults.  Then just use this custom in all your controllers when you need to access that information.  This way if you need to make changes, you have only one place to look.

Answer (score 0):

a function is all you need:

```
NSString * MONIdentifiedStringForID(NSInteger intID) {
    NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString * s = nil;
    if (intID == 1) {
        s = [userDefaults stringForKey:kSomeStuff];
    }
    else {
        s = [userDefaults stringForKey:kSomeOtherStuff];
    }
    assert(s);
    /* ... do a bunch of string parsing */
    return s;
}
```

if your classes have no relation, then you may simply wrap it as/if needed:

```
- (NSString *)getString:(NSInteger)intID {
    return MONIdentifiedStringForID(intID);
}
```